# How fast are the ships?

Tags: galaxir

There are 4 ships to upgrade to: Reaper, Rocker, Cruiser, and Hustler. Each has an attack and defense listed, but [the website](http://www.meryodev.com/meryodev/galaxir/galaxir/game.php) indicates ships are also characterized by speed. Does anyone have these numbers, or at least an ordering?